# Show that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f=0$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, alternative-proof, sequence-of-function

To any integer $n \geq 0$, we associate the function $f_n : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ defined by $$f_n(x)=x^n(1-x)$$
Show that $f_n$ converges uniformly.
I already have a proof involving $\sup\{f_n(x)-f(x)\}$ but I am looking for an alternative proof using something else.

Comment: The very definition of "converges uniformly" involves $\sup\{f_n(x)-f(x)\}$, so it's not totally clear what you're looking for ... do you want an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof?

Comment: By definition, you *have* to estimate the quantity $\sup_{x\in[0,1]} |f(x)-f_n(x)|$ if you want to show that the sequence $f_n$ uniformly converges to the pointwise limit $f$.

Comment: But if you only need uniform convergence (not caring about the limit), then you can try to show that the sequence is a Cauchy sequence in the space $C([0,1])$ with the sup norm assuming of course that you know $C([0,1])$ is a complete metric space. In that case, what you need is a uniform estimate for 
$$
|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|=|1-x||x^n-x^m|.
$$

Comment: The definition of "converges uniformly" my teacher gave us is $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists n_0$ such that $\forall n \geq n_0 \forall x \lvert f_n(x) - f(x) \rvert < \epsilon$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach:

If $0 \leq x \leq 1$, we have $x^n \geq x^{n+1}$ and thus $f_n(x) \ge f_{n+1}(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. Clearly we also have $\lim_n f_n(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, so $(f_n)_n$ is a non-increasing sequence that converges pointwise to a continuous function. By  [Dini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20the%20mathematical%20field%20of,then%20the%20convergence%20is%20uniform.), the convergence is also uniform.

Comment: Seems all good, thanks

Comment: You are welcome!